# Free Select-Filter Component for a Table in Blazor like Syncfusion

Tags: datagrid, blazor, components, blazor-server-side, syncfusion

Im looking for a free component like the Select-Filter in Syncfusion for Blazor. Ideally it should be for a Table and not a Grid. I have a Blazor Server App  and have a  table  which Gets data from my SQL Database. It is a project for a company but  as we are students from a school, we wont be able to use paid-versions of components, thats why I need a free one.
The Select Filter I  am talking about is this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOHZ8.png)

I tried it in Program already and and works perfectly, but the problem is it is not free.
Im trying to create my own component but it is really difficult.

I tried creating it on my own